# Fix Negative LOD Bias Intel HD GPU

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, gpu

When I turn on LOD on The Elder scrolls Oblivion, I get this weird blurriness on the ground textures. I've been told clamping my GPU driver will fix it, bit I can't find a way to do that.

I'm running Windows 10, 4 gigs of RAM, celeron dual core @ 2.4 GHz, intel HD GPU (Windows doesn't give a model number) with the latest driver

[image: Example]

Is there a way to clamp the GPU driver or fix this?

EDIT:
I found out that it's not the actual texture, it's almost like a fog. The image below was me crouching, almost like when you're partially submerged in water.

Comment: tI'm surprised that you can even game on that, even with an older game. Take a look at your system settings for the processor model and you can look up your GPU there

Comment: I can run FO 3 and Skyrim at minimal settings. I don't really play any graphically intensive games, so it doesn't bother me. I've looked everywhere, and it just doesn't give a model number. It just says "Intel HD Graphics"

Comment: Hence me asking *what's your processor?*

Answer (score 3):

Your scene contains more high resolution textures than your video card has enough memory to handle, your textures are not loaded and your scene appears in non-textured mode.

There isn't a setting that allows you to "enable/disable" clamping. The clamping you're referring to is actually done by the programmers. You could try to update your video card driver, but in reality your video card is not powerful enough to play Oblivion at that high of a texture mode. The video graphics card you have is integrated, which isn't the most ideal for gaming. A dedicated video card will perform much better.

Your best solution is to eventually get a new laptop that has better (dedicated) graphics, or build a desktop for gaming.

I'm actually surprised you can still run around when the texture isn't being loaded. I assumed the card would be overloaded and everything would come to a laggy halt.

Comment: I don't think that's the problem. Even with LOD on, I still get 40-60 FPS. Even when turning every other graphics option down, I still have that strange missing texture, but it's not everywhere, only on certain spots.

Comment: @kookerus LOD means level of detail?

Comment: @Kookerus I can also tell from the pictures you've uploaded, that it is clearly unable to render all the texture and therefore not loading.

Comment: There is no way you are getting 40-60 FPS with the hardware you have on.  How did you measure that your FPS exactly?

Comment: @DrZoo If you look at the second image, it is clearly loaded.

Comment: @Ramhound I opened up the console in the game and ran `tdt`, which toggles debug text and also shows the FPS counter.

Comment: @kookerus I completely disagree that the second image is fully loaded. I have no idea if the rocks/grass is supposed to be under the water like that. And your "water" is a grey/brown smear.

Comment: @DrZoo That "water" is the glitch I am experiencing. Underneath it, everything is loaded, I know for a fact.

Comment: @Kookerus I don't think you're understanding the answer I gave, and the fact that your GPU is not powerful enough to work on that level of detail.

Comment: @DrZoo Seeing as my GPU is fully rendering everything under that glitch, it very much IS powerful enough. All throughout this thread you've been telling me it's my hardware and every time you do I tell you, WITH EVIDENCE, that it isn't.

Comment: @Kookerus I see what you're saying, but you still have not showed any evidence that all of the detail in the scene is rendering. Again, it is not a "glitch". Both pictures that you have, clearly did not render the detail on the ground, and is displaying in non-texture mode. It drew the ground, but none of the textures are loaded. Here is a picture of Skyrim in [non-texture mode](http://www.geek.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/skyrim_lowres-590x343.jpg). This should be enough evidence for you to see that the exact same thing is happening in your case, except only some is missing (low VRAM).

Comment: That is not the ground in non-texture mode, as you can clearly see below the non-textured fog, as I have stated multiple times. That picture is not at all what is happening, as I have stated MULTIPLE TIMES. [Here's a crappy mspaint drawing of what's happening](http://i.imgur.com/Xm9IKDd.png)

Comment: There was an answer on [my post on Arqade](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/242688/fix-lod-texture-glitch-in-oblivion) that fixed my issue.